# Swipe to redirect to href location of hyperlink with class next

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I am looking for a way to use the regular jquery library to catch swipe events (left, right) to redirect to a href-location specified with a particular class (default navigation. ie: .next and .previous).

```
<a class="next" href="http://www.">next</a>

<a class="previous" href="http://www.">previous</a>
```

Comment: jquery supports swipe. Just add a listener on the swipe event and redirect the user

Answer (score 2):

```
$("body").on('swipeleft', function(e) {
  window.location.replace( $(".previous").attr('href') );
});

$("body").on('swiperight', function(e) {
  window.location.replace( $(".next").attr('href') );
});
```

Example: http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/

Comment: The thing is it has to follow the url of the href in the particular class. It cannot be a static Url.

Comment: This is not working on tablet when I swipe. I use this: `<a id="next-link" class="next" href="link">text</a>` Am I doing it right?